# how to location updates accurately while GPS turnoff also in iOS

Tags: ios

I need to get latitude and longitude values accurately even GPS off or on.anyone knows solution please send me.

Comment: Define "accurate".  GPS is the system that provides accurate location to about 10m in ideal conditions.  Without GPS you are going to have to rely on WiFi and cellular positioning, which is accurate to around 100m at best.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer is that you can't. As Paul W says in his comment, GPS is the subsystem on iOS devices that provides the most accurate location information. Without it the location manager has to use only secondary information like WiFi & cell tower locations, which are not as good.

I guess you could build a Lidar system and interface with that for indoor positioning, but something tells me that's not what you're asking for.